# Various problems when retrieving frames from IP cameras

Tags: c#, opencv, emgucv, ip-camera

I have 2 IP cameras and they are different models and both from the same manufacturer. Lets call them **Cam1** and **Cam2**. I want to retrieve frames from these cameras by their network address but there are some problems.

***Cam1:***

When using `frame = capture.RetrieveBgrFrame();` **frame** is always **null**.

When using `frame = capture.QueryFrame();` **frame** is **OK**.

***Cam2***(in the same network with my PC):

When using `frame = capture.RetrieveBgrFrame();` **frame** is always **null**.

When using `frame = capture.QueryFrame();` **WinForm** is frozen and computer(i7 3,3GHz, 6GB RAM) freezes.

Both stream addresses are OK. I tried to open them with VLC and also with OpenCV C++ platform.

**What could be a problem here?**

Here is the code:

```
using Emgu.CV;
using Emgu.Util;
using Emgu.CV.Structure;
using Emgu.CV.UI;

namespace IPcamera
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private Capture capture;
        private Image<Bgr, Byte> frame;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            try
            {
                capture = new Capture(camera_address);
            }
            catch (NullReferenceException exception)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(exception.Message);
            }

            if (capture != null)
            {
                Application.Idle += ProcessFrame;
            }
        }

        void ProcessFrame(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            frame = capture.RetrieveBgrFrame();
            if (frame != null)
            {
                pictureBox1.Image = frame.ToBitmap();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't usually work with IP cameras but I suspect that they don't start taking images when they are initialised. RetrieveBgrFrame() returns the las image taken by the camera, so if I am right RetrieveBgrFrame() will return null because the camera is not taking images by itself. Try to add the ProcessFrame handler to the camera event capture.ImageGrabbed instead of Application.Idle and check that it is even being called.

About the freeze, if it is a "low fps" freeze, it can be due to a slow camera, or to try to send big images over a slow bus. If it freezes forever check that there isn't any other application that can be using that camera and that you release the resources (are you trying cam1 before cam2 or trying cam2 in a new run?)

Comment: Thank you for your response. ImageGrabbed is never raised for both streams. WinForm is freezzed completely and other application have delayed reactions.

Comment: And are you using the cam2 in a clean run or using cam1 and then switching to cam2?

Comment: No switching, clean run only

Answer (score 0):

Could you replace

```
 Application.Idle += ProcessFrame;
```

with

```
 capture.ImageGrabbed += ProcessFrame;
```

And then RetrieveBgrFrame() method may retrurn the frame. That is how I normally do it and I have not had any problems. You may need to assign image to pictureBox1.Image using invoke.

```
 pictureBox1.Invoke((MethodInvoker) (() => pictureBox1.Image = frame.ToBitmap()));
```